# PIG : How to exclude first n lines while Loading

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

is there a way to exclude the first n lines of a file while loading some data on pig ?

I have a csv file that i would like to load but i have to ignore the first 3 lines.

Comment: Depending on how your csv file looks CSVExcelStorage (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be you can try like this.

```
A = LOAD 'input' <schema>;
B = RANK A;
C = FILTER B BY $0 > 3;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $1..;
DUMP D;
```

If you defined the schema in your load stmt then instead of positional notation($0,$1 etc) use the defined names. It will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
abt = LOAD 'act.psv' using PigStorage('|') 
as (r1:chararray,r2:chararray);

r = rank abt;

n = filter r by ($0 > 3);

p = foreach n generate r1,r2;

dump p;
```